# Coordinates as model features

Tags: machine-learning, prediction, dataset, predictor

My goal is to predict the taxi demand depending on location and time in NYC. Hence, among other variables my dataset contains coordinates. 
My question is, can I use them as a predictor for my models?

Clearly, for **linear regression** I cannot include the coordinates in my model. 
But what about **random forests**?

Comment: You may want to check out http://scikit-learn.org/stable/ too

Comment: Thank you Stoner. Could you please elaborate on your input?
I didn't find any information about handling coordinates on scikit-lern.org/stable.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is fine to include coordinates in the random Forest model.

Each decision tree would split according to the loss function, therefore, observations with "high demand" and those with "low demand" would be separated. If necessary, there would be multiple splits.